# Application Logs do not show in SystemOut.log in Wepsphere

Tags: logging, websphere, slf4j

We are using a java spark application that uses org.slf4j.Logger. In certain environments the application logs are written to SystemOut.log for the application server on WebSphere. However in certain other environments, no application log is written to SystemOut.log. What could be the difference in the environments. As far as we can tell, the deployment is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Any org.slf4j.Logger log statements you have will in turn use underlying Logger implementation (Commons Logging, Log4J/Logback etc.) to do the actual logging. slf4j picks the Logging implementation based of whats available in your classpath. Specifically, it looks for org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder provided in all these Logging implementations.  
In addition, Log level can be defined in the configuration file. If you have log4j in your classpath, it in turn uses a configuration file (usually a .properties file) like this -

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout  # Defines Log level. Only show INFO and up. Not DEBUG
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
..
....
```

1) Is the log level on such properties file different between your environments?
2) Websphere can also be configured to ignore certain Log levels in certain environments. E.g. Ignore DEBUG logs in Live/Production environments. Could this be causing your Logs to not show up?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply. The sl4j uses log4j and was picking up the log4j.properties file from websphere's installed location which had the wrong path. This was printing in SystemErr.log only once after the application was restarted. Issue was resolved once the path in the properties file was fixed